# Variable doesn't live long enough

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am a beginner in Rust and I am having a little trouble in understanding the concepts of **borrow** and **lifetime**.

I wrote this pretty straightforward code to read the contents of a file into a byte array.

```
fn file_to_bytes(filepath: &str)-> &[u8] {
    let mut s = String::new();
    let mut f = File::open("/home/rajiv/CodingIsFun/server/src/".to_owned()+filepath).unwrap();

    f.read_to_string(&mut s);
    let slice = s.as_str() ; 
    let bytes :&[u8] = slice.as_bytes() ;
    bytes
}
```

Its giving the following error.

```
 error: `s` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:36:17
   |
36 |     let slice = s.as_str() ; 
   |                 ^ does not live long enough
...
40 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 31:41...
  --> src/main.rs:31:42
   |
31 | fn file_to_bytes(filepath: &str)-> &[u8] {
```

I referred this [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/361vy6/how_to_get_around_with_does_not_live_long_enough/%20thread) on reddit which says that the variables declared later are destroyed first and therefore their lifetime will be shorter than the ones declared above, and this causes the error. But I still couldn't understand what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Please check whether the linked question answers your questions. If not, please describe what you still don't understand. If you know other programming languages (notably C and C++), it would be great to let us know as we could possibly phrase the explanations in a more tailored way.

Comment: The duplicate tells you why this is not possible, you should definitely read it! In your case, the simple solution is to return `Vec<u8>` instead of `&[u8]`. The former is an *owned* type, while the latter is *borrowed*.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Thanks! That helped. Anyways, I think I have to read the ownership module again.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I know C and C++. I think I'll read the concepts again and comeback if I still can't figure out. Thanks.

Comment: @Rajivteja: Coming from C and C++, Rust's `String` is C++ `std::string` and Rust's `&[u8]` is roughly C++ `char const*` (with size). Here, you would be returning a pointer into a local `std::string`, and the `std::string` would be destroyed at the end of the function... thus leading to a dangling pointer.